# How to make 301-redirect (with .htaccess) of specific pages with "?" in their urls?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

How to make 301-redirect of specific pages with "?" in their urls?

Example:
http://domain.com/cat/?id=1 
--->
http://domain.com/catalog/180/

I have a bunch of such urls. The IDs of old & new urls don't match!!!

**.htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
Redirect 301 /cat/?id=1 http://domain.com/catalog/180/
</IfModule>
```

The problem occurs because of "?" in urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **have** to use **mod_rewrite** (it has to be installed and enabled) as **you cannot match query string using `Redirect` directives unfortunately** -- mod_rewrite is the only known to me choice (unless you are happy to do it in your PHP/ASP/etc code).

```
# enable rewrite engine
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# the actual rule
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=1$
RewriteRule ^cat/$ http://domain.com/catalog/180/? [R=301,L]
```

The `?` at the end of new URL is used to discard current query string. Without it the new URL will look like `http://domain.com/catalog/180/?id=1`, which you do not want to.

The above rule is designed to be placed in .htaccess in website root folder (if placed elsewhere some small tweaking may be required) and will match `/cat/?id=1` ONLY.

---

If you want to match that URL with slightly different query string (like, extra parameter is present -- e.g. some tracking/referral info: `/cat/?id=1&source=sidebanner`), use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=1(&|$)
RewriteRule ^cat/$ http://domain.com/catalog/180/? [R=301,L]
```

Such additional query string parameter `source=sidebanner` will be discarded during redirect (because of `?` -- see original explanation above).

Comment: should I use [OR] between a bunch of these rules?

Comment: `[OR]` ?? It can only be applied to RewriteCond and not rules. Rules are standalone and are processed one after another. The best thing -- update your question (use separator & add what you have in mind -- the rules, how you want to use them) and I will confirm if it is OK or not (because comments do not allow proper formatting).